# Does outdated references cause errors in querying data?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a case where there are errors in updating data to tables in MS Access.

On the server file at work, there is a locked database file in MDB format, that cannot be accessed at all unless a shortcut is created adding the security.mdw in its properties path. On that database file holds the form which adds jobs, updates it, and deletes it from both a local table and a table stored through MySQL ODBC Ansi driver. How it does it is not the problem, for whenever I test the functions on both a Windows 10 (which doesn't show error on form open) and a slow Windows 7 computer that's causing "There is no object in this control" on form open, they run correctly.

But currently I have a problem stating that using that same locked MDB file, when someone else updated a status of a job, something with updating job data went wrong, as on the website (that shows mysql table data) wrong data shows. On another version of the form function, which is saved as .ACCDB (and editable), I have the following references:

1/ Visual Basic For Applications
2/ Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library
3/ OLE Automation
4/ Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 6.1 Library
5/ Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library
6/ Microsoft Windows Common Controls-2 6.0

While on the locked mdb file the references are...

1/ Visual Basic For Applications
2/ Microsoft Access 16.0 Object Library 
3/ OLE Automation
4/ **Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.1 Library**
5/ Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library
 
6/ Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library 
7/ Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library 
8/ Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library

Since the mdb file is locked, it cannot even save any changes made to the references list everytime the file is opened. So even when I added the dreaded MSCONCTL.OCX file that is causing the "There is no object in this control" on Windows 7 systems, but it's still causing that error.

So my question is as the title states. Would having outdated references cause error in querying data at times?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have both DAO and ADO, your code should always disambiguate, without exceptions. Don't rely on the reference priority to do the right thing for you.

Instead of `Dim rs As Recordset`, do either `Dim rs As DAO.Recordset` or `Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset`.

Also, the fact that MDB is locked and you mention a `security.mdw`, it sounds like it is using old workgroup security. I would get rid of that (it has no security value nowadays) and update the references. Both DAO and ADO has been updated since; you should be using the latest DAO (now named "Microsoft Office Access Database Engine Library") and ADO 6.1.

Comment: The VB code itself was making the differentiation even on the mdb version. DAO was only used for database linking, while ActiveX was used for a control only. This error was recieved when someone used it on the mdb file one time, so I was wondering if the outdated form elements/references were the cause of all this. Otherwise updating data via regular textboxes work fine.